# Missing data row in NOT IN clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, notin

I just realised that my Auto-Price Calculation doesn't fill the Prices for ListID 4.
I inserted the Prices from the SELECT shown below.

For bugg research I executed the SELECT without the WHERE part and it shows me the example data row.

I can't find the error though, why it is not shown in the complete select (it has no entry with ListID = 4).

Someone can see my mistake?

[image: Not In Error]

Edit: Just tried the subselect alone, it shows no rows for the requested article. Why is the NOT IN clause unaffected by this fact?
[image: subselect]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, it's because of how you are combining the `artikelnummer` and the `auspraegungID`.

I do not think you have accounted for that fact that `'100' + '0'` is idential to `'10' + '00'`.

Instead of trying to merge two fields into one, perhaps try the following?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  #allArticles  AS allArticles
WHERE
  Artikelnummer = 'IT-810260'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM KHKPreisListenArtikel
                   WHERE ListeID       = 4
                     AND Artikelnummer = allArticles.Artikelnummer
                     AND Auspraegung   = allArticles.Auspraegung
                 )
```

If that still doesn't work, then you *must* have corresponding records in that other table, find them like this...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  #allArticles            AS allArticles
INNER JOIN
  KHKPreisListenArtikel   AS Preis
    ON  Preis.ListeID       = 4
    AND Preis.Artikelnummer = allArticles.Artikelnummer
    AND Preis.Auspraegung   = allArticles.Auspraegung
WHERe
  allArticles.Artikelnummer = 'IT-810260'
```

***PLEASE ALSO NOTE***

Please don't include images of code, please copy the code, so that we can copy it too.

*Especially* when the tables/fields are in another language...

***EDIT***

Here is a query that will show the cause of your original query to fail.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  #allArticles            AS allArticles
INNER JOIN
  KHKPreisListenArtikel   AS Preis
    ON  Preis.ListeID       = 4
    AND Preis.Artikelnummer       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Preis.Auspraegung)
        =
        allArticles.Artikelnummer + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), allArticles.Auspraegung)
WHERE
  allArticles.Artikelnummer = 'IT-810260'
```

Comment: Article numbers have a unique schema. This can't be the problem I guess. Is it possible that the IN Operator does not work on varchar values?

Comment: Solution 2 does not work, since I want only the Articles with NO price in List 4. Solution 1 does work though, thanks a lot!

Comment: @SimonPawlowski - The `IN` operator will work fine.  But, your concatenation is still a potential hazard;  In your example you have a row of `artikelnummer = 'IT-810620', Auspraegung = 0`, and when concatenated you get `composite_key = 'IT-8106200'`.  If then you have a record in your other table as follows, you have a problem; `artikelnummer = 'IT-8106', Auspraegung = 200` because that will yield the same result of `composite_key = 'IT-8106200'`

Comment: @SimonPawlowski - Solution 2 isn't a solution! It's the code you could run to find any matches that could cause first query to fail!

Comment: I know the risks of this and I usually try to avoid it, but in this scenario its not possible to happen.

Comment: @SimonPawlowski - The fact that your query failed and the NOT EXISTS query worked suggests otherwise.  What do you get from the results of my final edit?